# Check if a path exists in a dictonary tree

Tags: python, coding-style, pylint, pep8, pep

I have a simple solution, but I think this is not the pythonic way. Do you have a suggestion?

```
def hasPath(myDict):
    try:
        myDict['A']['B']['C']
        return False
    except Exception:
        return True
```

Comment: This is ok, just catch a *specific exception(s)* that could be raised, e.g. `KeyError` plus any others